# Do I have to download yslow?

Tags: yslow

Is there no webpage where I just can input my URL and get something like yslow values?
It seems it should be easier than having to download the plugin for my browser. I usually don't program with firebug / yslow and I think it should be possible to perform a test like yslow by form submission.
Thanks for replying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any such service is likely to be overloaded pretty quickly, subject to rampant abuse, and not overly profitable.

A major point is that such a service would be in a high speed data center somewhere and so produce pretty useless results.  You want performance sampling at typical user endpoints, and it needs to be in a web browser.  Why duplicate a browser as a web service when you are sitting in front of one.

Note Google Analytics and Webmaster Tools attempt to perform some website performance metrics.

- http://www.google.com/analytics/
- http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/

Answer (score 1):

http://tools.pingdom.com/ will give you some information on how long resources in the page take to load, and the page weight, but tools like [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) and [PageSpeed](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/download.html) are a lot more informative.

If you do not want to install Firebug and plugins, abiding by as many of the [YSlow Best Practices for Speeding Up Your Web Site](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) as you can, will put you in good stead, prior to requiring any tools for fine tuning.